# How to invalidate pagination total-items?

Tags: angularjs, pagination, angular-ui

I am developing a directive to do searching, which will get different number of items in each search query, but it seems that pagination directive is not getting refreshed when it has to, as total-items is locked to "1" regardless of my efforts to change it:

[image]

Here is my view:

```
      <search-widgets>
          ..
          ..
          <pagination
                ng-model="currentPage"
                total-items="totalItems"
                max-size="maxSize"
                boundary-links="true">
          </pagination>
          ..
          ..
      </search-widgets>
```

And here is where I show the search query results:

```
function show_search_results(searchResults){
    scope.search_results= searchResults;
    // this has no effect:
    scope.totalItems= scope.search_results.length;
    }
```

I tried to use a timer to apply changes, but pagination directive didn't get updated

```
setInterval(function() {
             if(!scope.$$phase){
                 scope.$apply();
                 scope.$digest();
             }
         }, 1000);
```

Any one can help?

**EDIT**

Here is a plunker to make it more clear:

http://jsfiddle.net/tcVhN/49/

Comment: which version of angular-ui are you using? It's recently updated, but not updated the docs

Comment: Hard to tell the problem. Do you have a working example? Does the - 'pagination' directive have access to the correct scope? BTW. The angular counterpart of `setInterval` is `$interval(fn, delay, [count], [invokeApply], [Pass]);`

Comment: Yes,  'pagination' directive have access to the correct scope, I will try to upload a working example to show .. thanks

Comment: @Edward, I have AngularJS v1.2.28

Comment: Can you please check the plunker at the edit I've added at the answer above